# Math-education comparsion between Japan and United States from perspectives of engineering contributions

Tags: engineering

I may think that this post is unsuitable in HSM.

NASA launches rockets far more than JAXA(Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency).

BostonDynamics-robots are way general-purpose than Japan's FANUC-robots.

However when it comes to average math education level till 12,13th grade, Japan is far better than US.

But as I mentioned firstly, number of rockets or performances of robots are US's advantages.

It is very strange for me.

Just looking math-education till 12th grade, I think Japan should be more powerful than US in engineering however actually not.

Does anyone who can explain this?

BTW I am good at Japanese so I can search and share about education system in Japan as possible as I can, if you require me to do so.

Comment: The U.S. has the world's reserve currency.

Comment: Besides what @Alexandre Eremenko and Rodrigo de Azevedo have said, which I think provides the primary reasons, it is also useful to keep in mind that in the U.S. there is typically a huge gap between precollege rigor and undergraduate level rigor, and an additional huge gap (at least in math and the physical sciences) between undergraduate level rigor and graduate level rigor, at least when compared to many other countries. Thus, by focusing on math education up to 12th grade, you're focusing on what for most anyone who majors in math in the U.S. probably breezed through with very little work.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Considering gaps between highschool-course and bachelor course and master-course, then how us-raised students follow the difficult science courses taken in universities without exersized math problems? Many students drop off universities and only survived ones are just conspicuous?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I can't get the meaning, USD is the standard currency in the earth so as US want some expensive machine, then it is easy to earn that machine without spending much time to work?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think I got what you meant.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Japan has been becoming multicultural steeply in recent about 5 years..

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo: I disagree with your explanation. Japan is also a rich country which can hire anyone they want. They just don't do this. Their society is monocultural, while the US society is extremely diverse.

Comment: An appropriately revised version of this question -- what you asked in your comment, in reply to my earlier comment -- might be a good fit for [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I may ask a resemble question in that site.

Comment: I can recall a similar idea being asked during the 1980s when personal computers were becoming more widespread & computer games were being to proliferate. The question being along the lines of "why weren't the Japanese more innovative in terms of computer applications; why was it the English speaking world that was so prolific in the field?". The answers were nebulous but centered on the notion of cultural differences and modes of societal behavior in Japan were constraining the Japanese, whereas society in the US is freer encouraging people to be more adventurous in thought & application.

Comment: @Fred Interesting.

Answer (score 5):

The progress of technology is not a function of the state of education system. US imports huge number of highly educated people. Japan does not. Math education in most countries of East Europe is by far superior to the US (my first hand experience), but we do not have frequent news on breakthroughs in technology from East Europe. Instead, highly educated people from East Europe search for employment in the US.

Comment: I recalled the person who invented red led in US who immigrated from Ukraine.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EezdinoG4mk In this video of BostonDynamics , Except last person, the employees seems have English as mother language so at least in this case, your point seems not solving my doubht I think.